# UIWEbView transparent background: is possible?

Tags: html, uiwebview

i have this html page:
Code:

```
<html>
<!-- ... -->or explicity set the background-color CSS property to transparent:

<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
background-color: transparent;
}
</style>

<!-- ... -->
</head>
```

and a uivewbview with:
Code:

```
[webv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.8]];
[webv loadRequest....];
```

the page is displayed, but the background is white.
if i scroll the page before the beginning end after the end of the page, i can see the transparency (where the page is ont displayed)
can i have a ful transparent html page so i can see the background of uiwebview?
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just set the opaque property of the webView to NO

```
webv.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: also: [webv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];